# Migrate J2EE 1.4 to Java EE 7 Eclipse Indigo Jboss 7.1

Tags: java, jboss

I'm planning to migrate the application from J2EE 1.4 to Java EE 7. The target platform is Eclipse Indigo, JBoss 7.1, Servlet specification 3.0/3.1.

Questions:
What are the issues arises ? 
Is just changing the deployment descriptor (web.xml) ?
Does web services features exist in J2EE 1.4 ?
Should I create a new project and copy all the source code is better or there is better approach ?

Please enlighten this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things changed since 1.4, for example, enterprise java beans has new annotations, depreciating some of the JSF old anotations, and many other changes, so, yes, it's a hard work to do, the best you could do is to start a new project and add all the functionality (will be easy, JSF 7 has many, many advantages), then when it's ready replace the old one in production, all the changes will depend on how many features you are using, i really recommend to do the migration, especially after Java EE 5 i love Java EE, but in general and very probably will break a lot of code (xml's, configurations, views and other many things)